# Video controls have wrong size in Safari iOS

Tags: ios, css, video, safari

I am building an AR application with WKWebView in iOS and I am having the problem that, as soon as I put the video tag inside a container that has a css 3D transform, the video controls have a much smaller size than the video (see image below). I tried all combinations that I could think of, by setting or not setting the size of the video element itself or trying different values of object-fit or turning the controls attribute off and on at different points in the life-cycle of the video. All without success.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

[image]s.