# HTML video inside container wrong controls size in webkit

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, controls

In relationship with this question: [Video controls have wrong size in Safari iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817603/video-controls-have-wrong-size-in-safari-ios)

Same issue with Chrome (currently using version 62 for Mac), which in fact shows different (wrong) results if you apply the transformation to the container or the video itself.

Sample code and fiddle:

```
<style>
#div1, #vid2 {
  transform:scale(0.25, 0.25);
}
</style>

<div id="div1">
<video width="560" height="322" id="vid1" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" controls ></video>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<video width="560" height="322" id="vid2" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" controls ></video>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/julifos/z45xz63w/38/

Seems to be the same for mp4 and webm videos. Any help would be appreciated!

A curiosity: the size of the controls seems to depend on the size of the browser window (run the same fiddle with different window sizes).

[image: Sample 1]
[image: Sample 2]

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the dimension of the width and leaving the height dimension blank will fix this issue. It happens because If you set the two dimensions, and the actual video dimensions are not the same, it will scale to to the closest appropriate proportion using one dimension, thereby leaving blank margins at the only one dimension of the video player. The video may be centered either on the horizontal or on the vertical with blank space on either side.

from : [Control bar wider than video in html5 + css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335228/control-bar-wider-than-video-in-html5-css)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but doesn't seem like a valid fix. If you edit the sample fiddle and remove the height, you will see that there is no change in the behaviour.